# Two webprojects in the same Azure webrole?

Tags: c#, azure, web

I am trying to run multiple websites at the same web role. How it can be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creating a web role that contains multiple web sites is pretty easy.  Essentially, you need to add multiple  elements to your web role’s ServiceDefinition.csdef file.  Each  element would include a physicalDirectory element that references the location of the web site to be included.

```
<Sites>
  <Site name="WebRole1" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\WebRole1">
<Bindings>
<Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
</Bindings>
</Site>
<Site name="WebApplication1" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\WebApplication1\">
<Bindings>
<Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint2" />
</Bindings>
</Site>
<Site name="WebApplication2" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\WebApplication2\">
<Bindings>
<Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint3" />
</Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
```

**Referance:**

http://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/multiple-sites-in-a-web-role/

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433110.aspx

**Step By Step Approch Link:**

http://blog.elastacloud.com/2011/01/11/azure-running-multiple-web-sites-in-a-single-webrole/

Hope its helpful.